# Send data from multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have been searching how to send data between **multiple view controllers** but its only seem to be possible to send from one at a time?

I have five view controllers and I want to add text in to the **TextFields** I have in four of the five of them.

When I am in the last view I want to get the data from the four previous controllers.

Comment: Ah I see. Thought this was for iOS

Comment: Create a `DataContainer` class and instance of it, fill in the information bit by bit, pass the instance of the `DataContainer` along from each viewcontroller to the next.

Comment: Ok I will try to make it work. Thanks

Comment: You could also look at NSNotificationCenter and post notifications...

Comment: @fragilecat that will not work since the last viewcontroller does not yet exist and therefore cannot listen to events from the previous controllers.

Comment: Any good link to read about DataContainer?

Comment: that was an example class name, nothing specific, it is simply a class you create, chose a name that suits your data.

Comment: @luk2302 clearly I made an assumption and not the right one :( curious how do you know the lifecycle of the view controllers?

Answer (score -1):

You should use the NSUserDefault class.
With the NSUserDefaults class, you can save settings and properties related to application or user data. With NSUserDefaults you can save objects from the following class types:

NSData

NSString

NSNumber

NSDate

NSArray

NSDictionary.

I am 100% sure this link could solve your problem..
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-nsuserdefaults--mobile-6039

Comment: That is not the intended use of `NSUserDefaults`. The class is used for persistent storage, not to pass data from one view controller to the next. Also, consider a complex data structure: It would be silly to serialize the entire object just so it can be held in `NSUserDefaults`, simply to deserialize it in the next view controller.

Comment: Have now made a DataContainer class and passing in a value from the first view. Now when I try to get this value in my last view I getting fatal error: **"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values"**

Comment: There could be many reasons for that. Most likely it is a simple fix. Please help us help you by posting the code you are using. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamH. Here is my code from my first viewcontroller and the error is as well. [Here is a link to the code](http://pastebin.com/w6D1iwv4)

Comment: For one thing, it doesn't look like you are initializing your `DataContainer` instance. But also, I wanted to see how you were passing the data from one view controller to the next.

Comment: In the other viewcontroller I am doing the same as first almost. **"var dataContainer : Datacontainer!"** then i thought I just could fetch the data from the class. Seems that I am really off here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112616/discussion-between-alexander-mogren-and-adam-h).